# Mootools events question

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have the same code for keyup and keydown events, is there any way that I can pass the element to the function so I can call it like `element.addEvent('keyup',function(event,element));` on both instead of having to have an inline function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event.target to get the element I believe

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('yourInputField').addEvents({
       'keyup': alertValue,
       'keydown': alertValue
    });
});

function alertValue(event){
    alert(event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the event callback, `this` refers to the element that fired the event. So you can write either:

```
function valueChangeHandler() {
    console.log(this.value);
}
```

or instead, use the `target` property of the event object. Both work the same.

```
function valueChangeHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

Attach the callback function using either `addEvent` or `addEvents`:

```
$("someInputId").addEvents({
    "keyup": valueChangeHandler,
    "keydown": valueChangeHandler
});
```